# How to pass "extra" parameter to compose function

Tags: python, functional-programming, toolz

I' am searching for a way to compose function with an option to pass 'extra' parameter.

Example:

```
from toolz import compose_left

def g(a, b, c) -> int:
    return a + b + c

def f(a, b = 100) -> int:
    return a + b
```

when i do this:

```
compose_left(g, f)(1,2,3)
```

i get this:

```
106
```

cool.

but is there a way to define the parameter b and c from the function g in compose?

like this:

```
compose_left(g(b=2,c=3), f)(1)
```

now i get this:

```
TypeError: g() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
```

I am looking for a function or a package that can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `functools.partial`.

```
compose_left(functools.partial(g, b=2, c=3), f)(1)  # 106
```